te(x, by = factor) or s(x, by = factor)?
I'm trying to wrap my head around/put into words the meaning of an isotropic or anisotropic relation in the case of a linear term by factors (technical replicates). Would the use of s(x, by = factor) imply that the variation is somewhat proportionnal between replicates whereas te(x, by = factor) does not assume it? Would it be fair to say that s() shares more information between the different factors than te()?
Should I simply check the diagnostics to pick the best one?
The model i'm fitting is this one
y ~ te(dic, doc, bs = 'tp', k = 10)  + s(time, by = bioreactor, bs = 'tp', k = 5) + s(bioreactor, bs = "re")
y ~ te(dic, doc, bs = 'tp', k = 10)  + te(time, by = bioreactor, bs = 'tp', k = 5) + s(bioreactor, bs = "re")
dic and doc are inorganic and organic carbon concentrations (continuous variables), time is in days and bioreactors are a technical replicates.
Thank you for your help!

Isotropy applies to multidimensional not unidimensional smooths; so there will be little difference between te(x, bf = f) and s(x, by = f) (beyond differences between the default basis type, bs, and dimension k).
In the main body of your question you start to talk about s(x1, x2, by = f) and the te() variant te(x1, x2, by = f). Here isotropy is an important consideration. In the s(x1, x2) variant, we assume that wiggliness is the same in both x1 and x2, hence isotropy, and hence variables that are in different units typically shouldn't be modelled through a multidimensional thin plate spline with s(). The reason for this is that the basis itself is, in this case, 2D, using 2D basis functions, and a single smoothing parameter is used to control the wiggliness of the the surface generated from the 2D basis.
In the te() variant, we end up modelling a surface, but we do it by setting up separate bases one per margin of the tensor product, and then make them interact through a row-wise kronecker product operation. This means that we have two (in this case) smoothing parameters and these act to control wiggliness in x1 and x2 separately. Hence these are anisotropic smooths and hence allow easily for covariates measured in different units.

Would it be fair to say that s() shares more information between the different factors than te()?

No, I don't think it would be fair to say this. Beside from the fact that s(x, by = f) and te(x, by = f) shouldn't differ (if you set arguments to they use the same basis and basis dimension), all that a factor by does is arrange for separate smooths to be set up for each level of f. In both cases a separate smoothing parameter would be used for each smooth (because id is not set).

Should I simply check the diagnostics to pick the best one?

No, in general this would not be a good strategy. Even here where you are modelling two different forms of dissolved carbon, I would argue that you could see more variation in one of the covariate that the other and hence you should use te().
